# Horizontal space after tikzpicture[overlay, remember picture]

Tags: tikz-pgf, indentation, tikzmark, remember

I'm writing a document using a template that is not mine, in which, after an equation, some arrows are added using `TikZ`, by defining `tikzmark`s and using the `overlay, remember picture` options to the `tikzpicture` environment.

I've noticed that if one adds text immediately after `\end{tikzpicture}` then a little bit of white space is added at the beginning of the line. Here you can see a MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, arrows}

\renewcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

    \noindent\lipsum[1][1-3]

    \begin{equation*}
    \tikzmark{a} A = \tikzmark{b} B + C \tikzmark{c}.
    \end{equation*}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node (A1) [left of = a, node distance = 4.5em, yshift=0.8em]{\footnotesize lorem};
    \node (A2) [left of = a, node distance = 0em, yshift=0.25em]{};
    \draw[->, in=180, out=350] (A1.east) to (A2.west);
    \node (B1) [left of = b, node distance = 4.5em, yshift=1.9em]{\footnotesize ipsum};
    \node (B2) [left of = b, node distance = 0em, yshift=0.8em]{};
    \draw[->, in=150, out=350] (B1.east) to (B2.west);
    \node (C1) [right of = c, node distance = 4.5em, yshift=1.9em]{\footnotesize dolor};
    \node (C2) [right of = c, node distance = -0.5em, yshift=0.8em]{};
    \draw[->, in=45, out=210] (C1.west) to (C2.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \lipsum[1][1-3]

    \noindent \lipsum[1][1-3]

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output (I added the `geometry` package with option `showframe` to show the margins). Notice the sentence after the equation:
[image]

I tried to apply the solutions given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304477/curious-about-tikz-remember-picture-overlay-spacing) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460886/tikzpicture-with-remember-picture-and-overlay-inserting-vertical-space) (and the subsequent links cited there), but to no avail.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If using a recent version of tikzmark then your redefinition is unnecessary: use `\tikzmarknode` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tikzpicture` environment creates a zero size box, resulting in a new paragraph being started. The line ending between `\end{tikzpicture}` and the text will then show up at the beginning of the paragraph, following the zero size box.

You can get rid of it by placing a `%` immediately after `\end{tikzpicture}`.

Another solution is to move the `tikzpicture` *inside* the equation, i.e., move `\end{equation*}` down *after* `\end{tikzpicture}`. Then the space is in math mode, where it does no harm. Arguably, that is a more logical placement anyhow, as the arrows belong with the equation and not the following text.